# Arduino cc3000 Hangs on buildtest

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to get my Arduino configured with cc3000 to connect to wifi. I merely downloaded the example libraries, configured the SSID options and uploaded the code (this looks to be all I needed to do). When running the program, the build only goes as far as shown below, and hangs. No idea where to go from here.

[image: Serial Monitor]

```
    #define WLAN_SSID       "cc3000"        // cannot be longer than 32 characters!
    #define WLAN_PASS       "myPassword"
    // Security can be WLAN_SEC_UNSEC, WLAN_SEC_WEP, WLAN_SEC_WPA or WLAN_SEC_WPA2
    #define WLAN_SECURITY   WLAN_SEC_UNSEC
```

The above code is assumed to be the only thing I need to edit to get the build test to run, but I goes as far as the above image. Haven't found anything from searching online in the last few hours and starting to become frustrated.